# In Postgresql Query Yes And No in a table dynamically and Have a Summary in a list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I  have a  table  in  postgresql  with  may  columns  sample  is

```
"User",
"af12/af121j"
"af12/af121j",
"af12/af122c",
"af12/af122j",
"af42/af421c",
"af42/af421j",
"af42/af422c",
"af42/af422j",
"af43/af431c",
```

and many  more  columns  upto  300 and  they  have  rows with data and some  values   which have  yes and  no ,  how can i  query the  table in a  dynamic  way and  get  a result  of the  **NOs**  in the  table  and  get  a summary like  this

```
userA  "af12/af121j" ,"af43/af431c", 
userB  "af12/af121j","af12/af122c","af12/af122j","af43/af431c",
```

Sample Data from  select statement 
[image: Sample data analysig]

Comment: Where is userA, userB coming from? To answer this question provide at least a little more data. Show an example table with a few more columns, at least the columns from where userA an userB come from, but also one or more columns that have YES/NO-values.

Comment: @L.O.vanIngen added an  image that  has some of the data , and the  Users  come  from the  "g2/n28" column